# unable to play sound in chrome browser

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have put audio file in  in html but it's not playing in Google Chrome Browser.

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="{{asset("/storage/".$uploadedFile)}}" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="{{asset("/storage/".$uploadedFile)}}" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="{{asset("/storage/".$uploadedFile)}}" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

if you will download this into your device then it will play but not playing into browser.

Comment: As you state this problems occurs in Chrome: have you tested other browsers like Edge/Internet Explorer, Firefox etc.? It may also be helpful to include your browser version. This is found by navigating to `chrome://version/`

Comment: working in IE but in mediaplayer not in web. Also tested in opera and having same issue that audio is not playing.

Comment: What error messages does the console/network (F12) report?

Answer (score 0):

`mpeg` AND `mp3` seems exaggerated - usually an mp3 file is classified as `type="audio/mpeg"`, so might try to just do it like this:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="{{asset("/storage/".$uploadedFile)}}" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="{{asset("/storage/".$uploadedFile)}}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

.., where the second file would be an `.mp3` file